# Input field not getting populated when selecting multiple records in a table as aura:id does not support dynamic id

Tags: lightning-aura-components, record, aura-iteration, aura-id

I have a component which will display a list of records in the table format, and here I have a pick-list input field named Distance . Now on entering value in distance field and saving the record, record gets saved but the distance value is not getting populated in the record. If there is only one record, on entering distance value it will get saved and be populated. But when it handles more than one record, since aura:id inside aura:iteration is static , it throws an error component.get() is not a function.Since aura:id does not support dynamic id’s, I couldn’t get this done.

```
 Component:

<aura:attribute name="diss" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="distanceval" type="String"/>//This value is fetched from Server side Controller.

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.LocationFound}">   
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.Location}" var="location" >
                    <tr> 
                        <th>
                            <label class="slds-checkbox">
                                <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkLocation" value="" text="{!location.Id}"/>
                                <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
                                <span class="slds-form-element__label"></span>
                            </label>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Location Name">{!location.Name}</div>
                        </th>

    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Distance" >

         <lightning:select name="selectItem"  label="Distance to TrainingLocation" value="" aura:id="dis" >
         <option value=" " > --Select-- </option>
          <aura:iteration items="{!v.distancevalue}"  var="dist">
              <option value="{!dist.value}"> {!dist.label} </option>
            </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>
           </div>

    Helper.js:

    var distanceval=component.find('dis').get('v.value');
            console.log('the distance values is>>>>>'+distanceval);
             component.set("v.diss",distanceval);
            console.log('value is>>>>>'+component.get('v.diss'));
```

Comment: I have even tried using onchange event but it does not work fine.

Comment: May I know why aren't you using lightning:datatable for this requirement. It is easy to specify row level actions with base lightning:datatable component.

Comment: Yes. @Ashish sharma. Initially I tried with lightning:datatable ,but since I have a input field which is "editable=true" it automatically populates save and cancel button that does not seem to work in my case. Because I have a seperate save button for saving the record.

Comment: Yes, I think you cannot hide the save/cancel panel. I am not sure about any css hack if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `component.find` from `Aura:iteration` it gives array of components if that aura:iteration had more than one items, so you 'll to get list of distance values if aura:iteration had more than one item. you need to change the code to get list of distance values. try below code let me know if you get any issue.

helper.js

```
var lstdistanceval= [].concat(component.find("dis")).map(cmp => cmp.get("v.value"); // even it's working when you have single item in aura:iteration
        console.log('the distance values is>>>>>'+lstdistanceval); // here you 'll get list of distances you can tweek what ever you want
```

Comment: Thanks @sdandamud. This code works in fetching all the distance value I select in picklist field. When I set this value to an attribute , even then  I'm getting it in console. But when I assign it in action.setParams ,it throws an error.

Comment: var lstdistanceval= [].concat(component.find('dis')).map(cmp => cmp.get('v.value'));
        console.log('diatnce value is displayed as>>>>>'+lstdistanceval);
        component.set("v.diss",lstdistanceval);
        console.log('value in diss is>>>>'+component.get('v.diss'));
   
        var action = component.get('c.createRecord');  
     
         action.setParams({
             
            Name                   : component.get('v.name'), 
            Distance              :  component.get('v.diss')

});

Comment: i seen mistake here  aura"attribute "diss" is string type but you trying set the  list type of 'lstdistanceval', that's why you get error.

Comment: I just now changed it to list type, though it throws an error.

Comment: can you update your question with new Code and error so that i can replicate your issue and try to fix it

Comment: Thanks @sdandamud1. It worked fine. I was wrong in type conversion in my server-side. Now it works good. Again Thanks.

Comment: can you please do upvote if solution works for you for helping others.

Comment: Definitely. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this "[].concat(component.find("dis")).map(cmp => cmp.get("v.value");",so that everyone can better understand the code.

Comment: `component.find("auraid")` gives object type of particular cmp when you have only one component with that id, but in your case cmp used in side of aura:iteration that means `component.find("auraid")` returns array of cmp. `map` function do iterate array of cmps and get the value of each cmp and make the list of values. [].concat used for if you have one cmp that converts to array and used map function, because map works for only array.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks A lot .@sdandamud1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lightning:datatable for this requirement. You can avoid using aura:iteration over html table element & relying on aura:id to get selected values. Base lightning datatable component will do all the things without much code.

.cmp:

```
<lightning:datatable columns="{! v.mycolumns }" data="{! v.mydata }" keyField="id" onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }" />
```

.js:

```
({ 
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) { 
          var actions = [
              { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
              { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
           ]; 
          cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
               // Other column data here 
               { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions:       actions, menuAlignment: 'left' 
              } } 
         ]); 
    }, 
  handleRowAction: function (cmp, event, helper) { 
      var action = event.getParam('action'); 

     var row = event.getParam('row');
    switch (action.name) { 
       case 'show_details':
             alert('Showing Details: ' + JSON.stringify(row)); 
             break;
       case 'delete': 
           var rows = cmp.get('v.mydata'); 
           var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row);                
           rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
           cmp.set('v.mydata', rows); break;
    } 
})
```

Please refer Creating Static Row-Level Actions

section under documentation tab on this link[lightning datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation)

Using a base lightning component allows you to do most of the basic tasks without much coding. Salesforce has already provided most of the basic functionalities in base components that helps you to avoid coding each and every functionality by yourself. Its a good practice to use provided base components instead of html elements and replicating the functionalities which are already available. If you have something that's not available in base component, then you should go for complete implementation.